# Please help,Specialcharacter like bullet appears as square in title

Tags: php

I have given a project in which a user is entering information from
MS word ,I am storing it in phpmyadmin.Text with bullet stored in mysql table correctly.
Since the text is large,so I am
displaying it in title.

ex. It text is •Remove and destroy the infected plant debris in the field.
•Treat the seeds with Thiram 2g or Carbendazim 2 g or Thiram + Carbendazim (1:1 ratio) at 2 g/kg.
*output in td* Remove and destroy the infected plant debris in the field.
•Treat the seeds with Thiram 2g or Carbendazim 2 g or Thiram + Carbendazim (1:1 ratio) at 2 g/kg.
*But in title*
**square symbol** Remove and destroy the infected plant debris in the field.
•Treat the seeds with Thiram 2g or Carbendazim 2 g or Thiram + Carbendazim (1:1 ratio) at 2 g/kg.
This is my coding, all things are fine except title
I am writing my steps. Thanks
    while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

```
$disease_description_eng=ucfirst($res['disease_description_eng']);

$disease_sympton_eng=ucfirst($res['disease_sympton_eng']);

$disease_description_eng=showEncoding($disease_description_eng);
$disease_sympton_eng=showEncoding($disease_sympton_eng);
$test1=showText($disease_description_eng);
$test12=showText($disease_sympton_eng);

echo  "<tr>
<td>$test1<br/><a href='' class='link1' title='$disease_description_eng'>more</a></td> 

<td>$test12<br/><a href='' class='link1' title='$disease_sympton_eng'>more</a></td>
";        
}

function showEncoding($testencoding){
$test4enc=$testencoding;
$fromen=mb_detect_encoding($test4enc); 
 $test4enc=mb_convert_encoding($test4enc,'UTF-8',$fromen);
return($test4enc);
}
function showText($testt){
$test4=$testt;
$test4=substr($test4,0,20);
return($test4);
}
```

// I want no square in title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure about your encoding in mysql and full text is displaying correctly, it's probably about making substring.
Try to use `mb_substr` function instead of `substr` to make sure that there's no wrong character in your title.
More about `mb_substr`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: Please don't forget to  use mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");As, I did once.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your whole document is printed as UTF-8?

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Comment: I am using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">